# XSS - Ajax call return string assign to java script variable on jsp

Tags: ajax, jsp, xss

I am finding solution for few days, how to fix vulnerable java script variable that return from ajax call.

```
 public String getDefaultCopyName(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
     Long serviceGroupId) {
  MeoOptimizationSet set = service.find(serviceGroupId);
  String name = set.getName() + getCopySuffix();
  return name;
´}

  var defaultName = '';
  $.ajax({
     url: "<c:url value='/MeoOptimizationSet-getDefaultCopyName.mvc'/>", 
     data: { serviceGroupId: selectedIds[0] },
     success: function(data) {<b> defaultName = data</b>},
     async: false
  });

  APP.confirm({
  msg: "<br>"+label + "<br><br><input type='text' id='newName' size='40' 
  value='" + <b> defaultName </br> + "'  />",
  ok: function() {
    //TODO
     });
  }
  }
```

Comment: First Do the Question formatting. Add a clear description of what you intend to do

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated and I can't see any reason why you need it anyway, it just makes the user experience worse by locking the browser UI during the request. You can remove it. It's not related to your issue, just a general point.

Comment: Also your example is not clear. `success: function(data) {<b> defaultName = data</b>}` is not valid javascript and will give you a syntax error. Please fix your example and then explain what exactly is the problem, explain what is being returned from the ajax call and what precisely it is that you consider to be "vulnerable" and why?

Answer (score 0):

My questing is very simple, Just I want to know ajax call from JSP to java controller, Controller method return some value to JSPajax caller method and I am assigning value into a java script variable

```
var defaultName = '';
   $.ajax({
       url: "/abc.mvc", 
       data: { id: 1001},
       success: function (data) {
       defaultName = data
     }
  });
```

How could I protect dafalutName assignment from Cross Site Scripting (XSS)?